# Oracle: between dates statement gives error 'not valid month'

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to build an oracle query that I will be executing from my php project via oci. I need to select all records between a specific date range.

In trying to get the syntax down, I wrote out this test query:

```
SELECT * FROM SHIPPED
  WHERE user_seq_id = 381  AND 
  LOT_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('05/27/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
     AND TO_DATE('06/03/2014','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

This syntax seems like it should work but it's not. I'm definitely not an oracle developer so I'm positive I"m misunderstanding something. When I've looked at similar posts I haven't found anything that would point to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the `LOT_DATE` column's data type?

Comment: Thanks @dened, data type ended up being the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather tricky error.  The problem would occur if `LOT_DATE` were stored as a character string rather than a date -- and the string contained invalid data.

By explicitly converting the right hand side of the comparison to dates, the comparison is attempted by converting the field to a date.  And there is an error.

The fix is to fix the data in the field.  if something is in a field called "date", then it should probably have a date data type.

Comment: Ugh, yeah this is definitely a case of assumption and starting at a problem from the wrong end too long. I assumed that LOT_DATE would be a date type because, you know, why would it not be, but when I look at the dump the customer gave me it's definitely a varchar. I don't know how possible it will be for me to get them to change the data type on the column. If I can't get them to change it would wrapping the LOT_DATE in the to_date function be a suitable solution?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz . . . Using `to_date()` is quite viable assuming that the values follow a consistent format.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. The values definitely are a consistent format (which makes it even more frustrating that they're stored as a string instead of a date). Oh well! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For identifying unsupported string value for date - You can create a PL/SQL function which accepts string and validate for correct date format, sample of function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION VERIFY_DATE(v_date IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
    v_date1 DATE;
BEGIN
    select to_date(v_date) into v_date1 from dual;
        RETURN 1;
    Exception WHEN Others THEN
        RETURN 0;
END;
```

Now, identify rows which are having invalid string value for which you should correct to run your query:

```
select * from
(
    select VERIFY_DATE(LOT_DATE) DateVerified,s.* from SHIPPED s
) 
where 
DateVerified=0
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the tip. I can't add functions to the customer's database, but it's good to know how to handle this if I ever need to do this on projects where I do have control of the database.